# Как изменить docker образ из docker hub?

Tags: docker, weblogic, containers

Хочу добавить в докер образ WebLogic https://hub.docker.com/_/oracle-weblogic-server-12c действия - создать DS, пользователей, группы? Если создать новый dockerfile и в него записать команды, а затем создать новый образ на основе того, что из docker hub то команды выполняться после того, что было в первом dockerfile?

Comment: директиве from может предшествовать только директива arg: [ARG is the only instruction that may precede FROM in the Dockerfile](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#from). а директивы run и cmd (в которых только и могут быть использованы хоть какие-нибудь команды), естественно, будут идти **после** директивы from.

Comment: Спасибо за разъяснение. Нашел на гитхабе примеры dockerfile от oracle.